# PHP MySQL Zend-ACL - Graphically display ACL:

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-acl

I have one MySQL DB table like the following, the **resources table**:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | name      | type       |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 1  | guest     | user       |
| 2  | member    | user       |
| 3  | moderator | user       |
| 4  | owner     | user       |
| 5  | admin     | user       |
| 6  | index     | controller |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

---

Onto the next table, the **rules table**:

```
+----+---------+------+-------------+----------------------+
| id | user_id | rule | resource_id | extras               |
+----+---------+------+-------------+----------------------+
| 1  | 2       | 3    | 1           | null                 |
| 2  | 3       | 3    | 2           | null                 |
| 3  | 4       | 3    | 3           | null                 |
| 4  | 5       | 3    | 4           | null                 |
| 5  | 6       | 1    | 1           | index,login,register |
| 6  | 6       | 2    | 2           | login,register       |
| 7  | 6       | 1    | 2           | logout               |
+----+---------+------+-------------+----------------------+
```

---

OK, sorry for the length, but I am trying to give a full picture of what I am trying to do.
So the way it works, a role *(aka user)* can be **granted** *(rule: 1)* access to a controller, a role can **inherit** *(rule: 3)* access from another role or a role and be **denied** *(rule: 2)* access to a controller. *(A **user** is a resource and a **controller** is a resource)*

Access to actions are granted / denied using the extras column.

This all works, its not a problem with setting up the ACL within zend.

---

What I am now trying to do is show the relationships; to do that I need to find the lowest level a role is granted access to a controller stopping if it has explicitly been removed. I plan on listing the roles. When I click a role, I want it to show all the controllers that role has access to. Then clicking on a controller shows the actions the role is allowed to do.

So in the example above, a guest is allowed to view the index action of the index controller along with the login action.
A member inherits the same access, but is then denied access to the login action and register action.
A moderator inherits the rules of a member.

So if I were to select the role moderator. I want to see the controller index listed. If I click on the controller, it should show the allowed actions as being action: index. *(which was originally granted to the guest, but hasn't since been dissallowed)*

Is there any examples to doing this. I am obviously working with the Zend MVC (PHP) and MySQL. 
Even just a persudo code example would be a helpful starting point - this is one of the last parts of the jigsaw I am putting together.

**P.S.** Obviously I have the ACL object - is it going to be easier to interigate that or is it better to do it my self via PHP/MySQL?

*The aim will be, show what a role can access which will then allow me to add or edit a role, controller and action in a GUI style (that is somewhat the easy bit) - currently I am updating the DB manually as I have been building the site.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after I did abit of searching, and couldn't find an answer, I had a bit more of a think about this and here is the solution I came up with *(just incase its useful for someone else)*:

**Psuedo first:**

1. Show a page, listing all of the **roles** *(user levels)* from the ACL *`$acl->getRoles()`* as a link.
2. Click a link, reload the page passing the **role** as a parameter.

   - Now grab all the **controllers** from ACL *`$acl->getResources()`* checking that the resource insn't a role *(the array returned by getResources will also contain the roles)*.
   - loop through each **controller**, get all entries from the **rules** table where the **controller** id is in the resource_id field and explode the **extras** *(comma seperated actions)*
   - Next, loop through each **action**, calling `isAllowed` *(I have the role, controller, and action)*. **IF** at least one "allowed" is found, I colour the controller green *(allowed access to at least one action in the controller)*, otherwise its red *(no access to anything in that controller)* each list item being clickable to reload the page
3. Now when a controller is clicked, I reload the page, now, when running through the list of actions, calling `isAllowed` I create a list of the actions for the selected controller, colouring the action green or red based on the result of `isAllowed`

The answer its self is almost as long winded as the question, but it works for me, giving a very clear picture of what each role can do. Here it is if its going to help anyone:

**Now for the code:**

AdminController:

```
public function aclAction()
{
    $this->view->content_title = "Access Rules:";

    // Get the ACL - its stored in the session:
    $usersNs = new Zend_Session_Namespace("ZEND_SITE");
    $acl = $usersNs->acl;

    // List all Roles in the ACL:
    $roles = $acl->getRoles();
    // Pass the roles to the view:
    $this->view->roles = $roles;

    // Check if a role has been clicked on:
    $role = this->_getParam('role');
    if(!is_null($role))
    {
        // Pass the role to the view:
        $this->view->role = $role;

        // Get all the resources (controllers) from the ACL, don't add roles:
        $controllers = array();
        foreach ($acl->getResources() as $res)
        {
            if (!in_array($res, $roles))
            {
                $controllers[] = $res;
            }
        }

        // Create a Rules Model:
        $rules = new Model_ACLrules();

        // Store controllers + access:
        $all_controllers = array();

        // Check if the controller has been passed:
        $cont = $this->_getParam('cont');

        // Loop through each controller:
        foreach ($controllers as $controller)
        {
            // Get all actions for the controller:
            // THIS IS THE PART I DON'T LIKE - BUT I SEE NO WAY TO GET
            // THE RULES FROM THE ACL - THERE LOOKS TO BE A METHOD
            // BUT IT IS A PROTECTED METHOD - SO I AM GETTING THE ACTIONS 
            // FROM THE DB, BUT THIS MEANS TWO SQL QUERIES - ONE TO FIND
            // THE RESOURCE FROM THE DB TO GET ITS ID THEN ONE TO FIND
            // ALL THE EXTRAS FOR IT:
            $all_rules = $rules->findAllActions($controller);

            // Store if the role is allowed access somewhere in the controller:
            $allowed = false;

            // Store selected controller actions:
            $cont_actions = array();

            // Loop through all returned row of actions for the resource:
            foreach ($all_rules as $rule)
            {
                // Split the extras field:
                $extras = explode(",", $rule->extras); 

                // Check if the role has access to any of the actions:
                foreach ($extras as $act)
                {
                    // Store matching selected controller:
                    $match = ($cont==$controller)?true:false;

                    // Store the action if we are looking at a resource:
                    if ($match)$temp = array("action"=>$act,"allowed"=>false);

                    // Check if the role is allowed:
                    if ($acl->isAllowed($role,$controller,$act))
                    {
                        // Change the controllers allowed to ture as at least one item is allowed:
                        $allowed = true;

                        // Change the matched controllers action to true:
                        if ($match)$temp = array("action"=>$act,"allowed"=>true);
                    }

                    // Check if the action has already been added if we are looking at a resource:
                    if ($match)
                    {
                        $add = true;
                        // This is done because there could be several rows of extras, for example
                        // login is allowed for guest, then on another row login is denied for member,
                        // this means the login action will be found twice for the resource,
                        // no point in showing login action twice:
                        foreach ($cont_actions as $a)
                        {
                            // Action already in the array, don't add it again:
                            if ($a['action'] == $act) $add = false;
                        }
                        if($add) $cont_actions[] = $temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Pass a list of controllers to the view:
            $all_controllers[] = array("controller" => $controller, "allowed" => $allowed);

            // Check if we had a controller:
            if(!is_null($cont))
            {
                // Pass the selected controller to the view:
                $this->view->controller = $cont;

                // Check if this controller in the loop is the controller selected:
                if ($cont == $controller)
                {
                    // Add the controller + actions to the all rules:
                    $this->view->actions = $cont_actions;
                }
            }
        }

        // Pass the full controller list to the view:
        $this->view->controllers = $all_controllers;
    }   
}
```

Next the view: acl.phtml:

```
<h2>Roles:</h2>
<ul>
    <?php 
        foreach ($this->roles as $name)
        {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$this->baseUrl('admin/acl') . '/role/' . $name . '">' . ucfirst($name) . '</a><br/></li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>

<?php if (isset($this->controllers)): ?>
    <h2><?php echo ucfirst($this->role); ?>'s Controllers:</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php
            $array = $this->controllers;
            sort($array);
            foreach ($array as $controller)
            {
                $font = ($controller['allowed'])?'green':'red';
                echo '<li><a href="'.$this->baseUrl('admin/acl') . '/role/' . $this->role . '/cont/'.$controller['controller'].'" style="color:'.$font.';">'.ucfirst($controller['controller']).'</a></li>';    
            }   
        ?>
    </ul>

    <?php if (isset($this->controller)): ?>
        <h2><?php echo ucfirst($this->role)."'s, ".ucfirst($this->controller);?> Actions:</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php 
                $array = $this->actions;
                sort($array);
                foreach ($array as $action)
                {
                    $font = ($action['allowed'])?'green':'red';
                    echo '<li><font style="color:'.$font.';">'.ucfirst($action['action']).'</font></li>';
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Example:

[image]

I hope this is helpful to someone, I will leave it open for now incase anyone can suggest a better solution - or maybe improve on the answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function aclAction()
{
    $this->disableView();

    $service = $this->service()->acl();
    $acl = $service->getAcl();
    $roles = $acl->getRoles();
    $resources = $acl->getResources();
    $results = array();

    // load XML to get all rules & roles & actions
    $configdata = $service->getConfigdata();

    $actions = array();
    foreach ($configdata['rules']['rule'] as $rule){
        if(isset($rule['action'])){
            if(!is_array($rule['action']))
                $rule['action'] = array($rule['action']);
            foreach($rule['action'] as $action){
                $actions[$rule['resource']][$action] = $action;
            }
        }

    }

    $results[] =
    '<thead>'
    .   '<tr>'
    .       '<th>Resource</th>'
    .       '<th>Action</th>'
    .       '<th colspan="'.count($roles).'">Roles</th>'
    .   '</tr>'
    .   '<tr>'
    .       '<th></th>'
    .       '<th></th>';

    foreach ($roles as $role){
        $results[] = '<th>'.$role.'</th>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $results[] = '</tr></thead>' . PHP_EOL;
    $results[] = '<tbody>';

    foreach ($resources as $resource){

        $results[] = '<tr><th>'.$resource.'</th><td>-</td>';
        foreach ($roles as $role){
            $test = $acl->isAllowed($role, $resource);
            $results[] = '<td'.($test?' class="green"':' class="red"').'>'.($test?'YES':'NO').'</td>';
        }
        $results[] = '</tr>';

        if(isset($actions[$resource])){
            foreach ($actions[$resource] as $action){

                $results[] = '<tr><th>&rarr;</th><td>'.$action.'</td>';
                foreach ($roles as $role){
                    $test = $acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $action);
                    $results[] = '<td'.($test?' class="green"':' class="red"').'>'.($test?'YES':'NO').'</td>';
                }
                $results[] = '</tr>';
            }
        }
    }

    echo
    '<style type="text/css">'
    .   'html, body, table {font-family:verdana;font-size:14px;}'
    .   'table {border-spacing:1px;background:#CCCCCC;}'
    .   'td, th {background:#ffffff;padding:5px;}'
    .   'th {text-align:left;}'
    .   'tr:nth-child(even) td, tr:nth-child(even) th {background:#C2DBEF;}'
    .   '.red {color:red;font-weight:bold;}'
    .   '.green {color:green;font-weight:bold;}'
    .'</style>'
    .'<h1>$role is allowed to $resource ?</h1>'
    .'<table>'.implode('', $results).'</table>';

}
```

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tR3g.png (i cant post images as im a guest here)
I copied it from my project - hope it helps. It looks very nice in action but you need a properly formed xml with all the rules etc.